# Visual Studio 2013 - Open .aspx and .cs files from other project at the current project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Probably it's a stupid question but i would like to open aspx and cs files from the windows explorer without opening a new instance of visual studio, is this possible?

Greets,
Firmino

Comment: I can't, VS does not allow me to do that but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad your VS allow you to drag aspx files, but i'm telling you i can't! That's why i opened this question, to try to understand what's wrong with my VS.

Comment: Are you trying to drag it into a document or the toolbar? Sometimes dragging to a document interprets it differently. Just tested it on VS2013 Express for Web and it works.

Comment: I'v tried to drag it around all VS and i just can't, i use VS2013 Professional but i will try later at home with VS2013 Express for Web. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can improve your experience opening files in VS.

- You can use drag and drop

  Troubleshooting: You can't drag and drop between apps in Windows if one of them is running with admin rights and another is not. Normally, you don't need either of Explorer or VS to run with admin privileges.
- Visual studio running with no admin rights will most likely will be reused to open a file when you doubleclick in the Explorer (sometimes it still opens new instance with no sensible reason)
- You can use `File_Menu->Open->File` (Ctrl+O). This will basically open an Explorer instance for you.
- You can use `File_Menu->Recent files` if you have opened desired file recently
- You can just add file to the project (and then get rid of it when it's no longer needed) (Shift+Alt+A)
- You can use `Show All Files` feature (a toggle button in Solution Explorer) to view all the files under project folder (recursively), even if they are not included in the project. You cannot see folders higher in hierarchy, but you could make for example a symlink or just a dumb copy
- You can file a feature request or a bug report (it can be done from VS itself) to make developers know about this situation

Hope any of those solutions will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! That was an awesome explanation, i was running VS with admin rights and that really was the problem. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click On The File 
Click Open With
And Select Notepad..

It Would Do The JOB

Comment: It would do other job but not the desired job. Thanks anyway.